# Python Reg ex needed to read till end of the line \n

Tags: python, regex

Below is my byte class, am trying to read data till Suj using regex like below

```
stderr=b'ok: [localhost] => () fatal: [localhost]: Failed! => {"changed":true,"stdout":"Error": Invalid user or pwd\nJoin AD\n Suj}'
```

Regex#

```
searchVal= re.search(r'fatal: \[localhost\]: Failed! =>(.*)[\n$](.*)',stderr.decode('utf-8'))
```

but above reg ex is giving response till first '\n', but I want to read till end i.e second `\n`. I am not sure what is missing, any clue would be appreciated.

The response needed is like "changed":true,"stdout":"Error": Invalid user or pwd\nJoin AD\n Suj}". But am getting like"changed":true,"stdout":"Error": Invalid user or pwd\nJoin AD".

Thanks for your time

Comment: try `re.search(r'fatal: \[localhost\]: Failed! =>(.*)(?:[\n$](.*))+',stderr.decode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the use of the dot character, which doesn't match new-line by default. use the `DOTALL` flag to change that:

```
stderr=b'ok: [localhost] => () fatal: [localhost]: Failed! => {"changed":true,"stdout":"Error": Invalid user or pwd\nJoin AD\n Suj}'
exp = re.compile(r'fatal: \[localhost\]: Failed! =>(.*)[\n$](.*)', re.DOTALL)
res = exp.search(stderr.decode('utf-8'))
res.group() # Results in the following:
```

Result:

```
'fatal: [localhost]: Failed! => {"changed":true,"stdout":"Error": Invalid user or pwd\nJoin AD\n Suj}'
```